# What does Public Class [Interface] mean in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I saw the following class declaration in vb.net:

```
Public Class [Interface] Implements TestInterface
```

What does the above mean?  Is there an equivalent in c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a normal class that is named `Interface`.

Since `Interface` is also a keyword, it must be wrapped in brackets to force the compiler to parse it as an identifier.

In C#, you can write  `public class @interface : TestInterface`  (It must be lowercase to conflict with the C# keyword).

---

In either language, **don't do this**.  It's confusing and serves no purpose.

Comment: Wow, it confused me from the beginning.  Yes I agree, this should not be done.  Thanks for the answer.